# Adding validation with MVC 3 & jQuery Validator in execution time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a form with validation rendered by c# when the page is loaded, 
the rendered fields like so:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Idade must be a number." data-val-range="message here" data-val-range-max="25" data-val-range-min="16" data-val-required="The Idade field is required." id="Content_MyFieldId" maxlength="3" name="Content.MyFieldId" value="0" type="text">
```

and I'm trying put a new html object equals the example with jQuery, but this new field is not validated when I submit the form.

Have a way to add validation in this field using jQuery?

**PS: I don't want to use manual method like so:**

```
$("#field").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Required input"
    }
});
```

Because I have the rules in the input field, I only want to apply it.

Comment: So you are using Unobtrusive Client Validation currently, but fields you add dynamically are not being validated?

Comment: can you provide a sample? You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Feels like a bit of a hack, but here's how I've done it.

```
// Target Form
var $form = $("**form selector**");

// Unbind existing validation
$form.unbind();
$form.data("validator", null);

// Check document for changes
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

// Re add validation with changes
$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
```

Rich

Comment: @kim3er Hi, thanks, but $.unobtrusive.parse(document) says that $.unobtrusive is undefined, and if I use $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document) says only undefined (both in firebug).

Comment: @Cesar You're right. in MVC3 they've moved the jQuery into an enclosure. The parsing function must be exposed some other way. I'll have a closer look.

Comment: @Cesar, sorry ignore last comment. `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` is exposed in my example page.

Comment: @Cesar And yet no affect on the jQuery validation settings. This was a lot easier in MVC2. I'll run some more tests.

Comment: @kim3er Ok, thank you. I'm trying too, but without success yet;

Comment: I have exaxtly the same problem, but after using your code, it says "Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined"

Comment: Sorry, I should pass the form id, rather the place holder id that holds the partial view. It works, great thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I solved here using

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement($("#element")[0], false);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent($("#element")[0]);
```

parseDynamicContent I got [here](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/)

Comment: This don't work because in field name has "." and "[]". Thanks

Comment: @Caser: solved by `var id -document.getElementByName(name)[0].id;` and than use ID instead of name in jquery selecotor, it works form me

Comment: You saved my day! However, the second line of your code did not work for me, `parseDynamicContent` was unknown. It was not necessary either.