# disable enable unobtrusive validation mvc

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have a wizard which contains a very large form.  The wizard has an area where the user chooses one of two options which shows and hides a div with other input elements.  The problem is that the hidden elements are being validated and i need to turn validation off on those certain elements.

I've tried:
$('.data-panel').find('input[type="text"], textarea, select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

as state in this thread, but it will still validate those input elements.
[MVC3 unobtrusive validation: how to remove/re-attach validation from a group of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673626/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-how-to-remove-re-attach-validation-from-a-group-of)

I thought about injecting/remove a partial view, but those elements won't validate when they need to be validated.

I'm opening for any work arounds.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To disable:

```
$('.data-panel').find('input[type="text"], textarea, select').prop('disabled', true);
```

To enable:

```
$('.data-panel').find('input[type="text"], textarea, select').prop('disabled', false);
```