# set nullable if not visible with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which is controlled by a regex:

```
    [RegularExpression("[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1},[0-9]{2}")]
    public string HighestValueStringDistance { get; set; }
```

It works fine but sometimes the textbox is unvisible (using javascript)
How can I set it nullable only if it is not visible?

Thanks

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
jQuery.validator.defaults.ignore = ":hidden";

// the line above is outside any $(document).ready(...) or similar
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
});
...
```

Source: [MVC 3 unobtrusive validation - conditionally disable/enable validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816471/mvc-3-unobtrusive-validation-conditionally-disable-enable-validation)

Comment: thanks but they now they don't get visible anymore, do you now why?

Comment: I does work, they are now nullable but they don't get visible anymore, also not if they need to be visible

Comment: 'jQuery.validator.defaults.ignore' shouldn't have an impact of the visibility of your dom elements, can you explain what have you done exactly? It might be something else.

Comment: You didn't include the part with the 'jQuery.validator.defaults.ignore = ":hidden";' and the part with 'ResultType' radio buttons.

Comment: Why are your radio buttons hidden? Why is everything hidden? Also try to put the script at the top of everything.

Comment: because it may only be visible if officialevent is checked, is this checkbox is checked the radiobuttons become visible and than the textbox if a radiobutton is checked..