# Dynamically added fields to form aren't being validated

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Consider the following JS code in ASP MVC application

```
function AddRecipient() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Recipient/Add/@Model.Email.Id",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#RecipientsTable tr:last").after(html); }
    });
};
```

The newly added fields in the new table row will not be validated by the form validator.
I believe I need to add those fields to the form validator.

Any idea how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is kinda a pain you are mixing javascript with razor. They are in 2 different contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: 
[Adding validation with MVC 3 & jQuery Validator in execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104288/adding-validation-with-mvc-3-jquery-validator-in-execution-time)

```
// Target Form
var $form = $("**form selector**");

// Unbind existing validation
$form.unbind();
$form.data("validator", null);

// Check document for changes
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

// Re add validation with changes
$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
```