# C# ASP.NET MVC - dynamically adding textbox if any index value is missing below ids are not binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I implemente dynamic add and remove column it's working fine if I remove last row but if I remove first index then it's losing all other rows.

But if I use FormCollection Its binding but not as array list

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var employee = new Employee();
    employee.Skills.Insert(0, new Skill());

    return View(employee);
}
```

**.cshtml**

```
 <table id="skills-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20px;">&nbsp;</th>
                <th style="width:160px;">Skill</th>
                <th style="width:150px;">Level</th>
                <th style="width:32px;">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Skills.Count; j++)
            {
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th><span class="rownumber"></span></th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Skills[j].Title, new { @class = "skill-title" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills[j].Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            model => model.Skills[j].Level,
                            new SelectList(WebApplication4.MetaModels.SkillLevel.GetSkillLevels(), "Code", "Description", Model.Skills[j].Level),
                            "-- Select --",
                            new {@class = "skill-level"}
                            )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills[j].Level)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (j < Model.Skills.Count - 1)
                        {
                            <button type="button" class="remove-row" title="Delete row">&nbsp;</button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <button type="button" class="new-row" title="New row">&nbsp;</button>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addRow = function () {
        addTableRow($("#skills-table"));
        return false;
    };

    var deleteRow = function (event) {
        $(event.target).closest("tr").remove();
        return false;
    };

    function addTableRow(table) {
        /* Sources:
        http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/adding-a-row-to-a-table-containing-form-fields-using-jquery-18
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104288/adding-validation-with-mvc-3-jquery-validator-in-execution-time
        */

        var $ttc = $(table).find("tbody tr:last");
        var $tr = $ttc.clone();

        $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", function () { // find name in the cloned row
            var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)_(\d+)__(\D+)$/); // extract parts from id, including index
            return parts[1] + "[" + ++parts[2] + "]." + parts[3]; // build new name
        }).attr("id", function () { // change id also
            var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)_(\d+)__(\D+)$/); // extract parts
            return parts[1] + "_" + ++parts[2] + "__" + parts[3]; // build new id
        });
        $tr.find("span[data-valmsg-for]").attr("data-valmsg-for", function () { // find validation message
            var parts = $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for").match(/(\D+)\[(\d+)]\.(\D+)$/); // extract parts from the referring attribute
            return parts[1] + "[" + ++parts[2] + "]." + parts[3]; // build new value
        })
        $ttc.find(".new-row").attr("class", "remove-row").attr("title", "Delete row").unbind("click").click(deleteRow); // change buttin function
        $tr.find(".new-row").click(addRow); // add function to the cloned button

        // reset fields in the new row
        $tr.find("select").val("");
        $tr.find("input[type=text]").val("");

        // add cloned row as last row
        $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);

        // Find the affected form
        var $form = $tr.closest("FORM");

        // Unbind existing validation
        $form.unbind();
        $form.data("validator", null);

        // Check document for changes
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

        // We could re-validate with changes
        // $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
    };

    (function ($) {
        /* Source:
        http://www.johnculviner.com/post/2011/11/16/ClearReset-MVC-3-Form-and-Unobtrusive-jQuery-Client-Validation.aspx
        */

        $.fn.resetValidation = function () {
            var $form = this.closest('form');

            //reset jQuery Validate's internals
            $form.validate().resetForm();

            //reset unobtrusive validation summary, if it exists
            $form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
                .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
                .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
                .find("ul").empty();

            //reset unobtrusive field level, if it exists
            $form.find("[data-valmsg-replace]")
                .removeClass("field-validation-error")
                .addClass("field-validation-valid")
                .empty();

            return $form;
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(function () {
        $(".new-row").click(addRow);
        $(".remove-row").click(deleteRow);
    })
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(Employee employee, FormCollection abc, string[]dynamic)
{
    return View(employee);
}
```

Here my `FormCollection` is getting all the data but not as array type

Comment: What does the delete button button, when you initially render the page? You only bind the deleterow functionality when you add the via the jquery

Comment: It's a known "feature" that binding to `array[]` requires indices to be in order.  You can either re-order (tedious, prone to errors) or add a hidden field such as "active" and set it to 0 (and bind)

Comment: My advice is not to delete item from the array. Add "deleted" property to the item and mark it on deletion. After POST you can filter only not deleted items to process.